# Retrieving values from a kivy dropdown widget

Tags: kivy

How would I go about retrieving a selected item from the dropdown? Here is what I have so far.

This is the kv file:

```
<User_Interface>:
    FloatLayout:
       Spinner:
           size_hint: .1,.1
           pos_hint: {"x":0,"top":1.}
           pos: 10,10
           id: spinner_id
           text: '<select>'
           values: root.buildLists()
```

And here is the python file:

```
class User_Interface(FloatLayout):
    def buildLists(self):
        list = self.ids.spinner_id.values = list[ 'A','B','C']
        return list
```

So for instance if I select A I would like to return it to a method...

I hope it makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the text event to a method in the class. for example:

in your kv file set an id to your spinner like:

```
id: spin
```

In you python code into the **init** method of your User_Interface class you can put something like this:

```
self.ids.spin.bind(text=showmethetext)
```

Then, in your class define the method `shomethetext` like:

```
def showmethetext(self, text):
    print text
```

And voila! It should work I guess.

Bye

Comment: You are wellcome, de nada ;)