# Kivy - Drop-down List - How to get current text from selected button?

Tags: python, kivy

In the following code, there is a button that when pressed shows a drop-down list with 9 Values. 
Once I select one of these options, I would like to print on Python what is the value that I selected. 
For example, if I select "Value 4", in the moment that I select "Value 4" this value has to be printed in my code.

I found some similar question about this, and I provide the link below, although none of them solved my problem. 
[Python, Kivy. Get text from dynamically created buttons with a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759993/python-kivy-get-text-from-dynamically-created-buttons-with-a-dropdown) 
[Retrieving values from a kivy dropdown widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552832/retrieving-values-from-a-kivy-dropdown-widget)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        label = Label(text = 'LABEL')
        button = Button(text='Selecione', font_size=30, size_hint_y=0.15 , on_release = self.lista)
        box.add_widget(label)
        box.add_widget(button)

        return box

    def lista(self, button):
        dropdown = DropDown()

        for index in range(10):
            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.text = 'Value %d' %index
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(button, 'text', x))
        print(button.text)

Test().run()
```

I need to print the text of the selected "button" in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add a `dropdown.open(button)` to the `lista` function, for the dropdown to open when called from the first button.

You don't have to re-bind the `release` of the first button every time you call the `lista`.

You also have to create the `dropdown` once, not with every call to the `lista`. The same goes for its buttons too...

But you have to keep a reference of it, so you can use it inside the `lista` function.

And finally, you have to bind the `on_release` attribute of every dropdown button to a print action.

```
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        label = Label(text='LABEL')
        button = Button(text='Selecione', font_size=30, size_hint_y=0.15, on_release=self.lista)
        box.add_widget(label)
        box.add_widget(button)

        self.dropdown = DropDown()  # Create the dropdown once and keep a reference to it
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(button, 'text', x))

        for index in range(10):  # create the buttons once
            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44,
                         on_release=lambda btn: print(btn.text))  # bind every btn to a print statement
            btn.text = 'Value %d' % index
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        return box

    def lista(self, button):
        # dropdown = DropDown()  <---- DON'T NEED THIS
        # button.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)  <---- DON'T NEED THIS
        self.dropdown.open(button)  # you need this to open the dropdown
        # print(button.text)


Test().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.
It worked fine!
I added a button on the boxlayout called "update" and I would like to print the btn.text every time I release the button "update".
I tried to add a global variable and make --> global variable = btn.text, but it does not work. 
How could I print the btn.text every time I release the button "update"?

Comment: @JoseGuilherme If my answer, answered your question, don't forget to accept it. If you have an other question, perhaps it is better for everyone searching, to ask it at a separate thread with some demonstrative code..